# Dark theme in applications not consistent with chosen custom theme - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

So I like to use a custom theme. But I also like to switch between light and dark themes depending on the room illumination level to preserve my eyes. So I use "Materia-dark-compact" for the night and "Materia-light-compact" for the day, switching between them in Tweaks. It works fine but the apps that "can respect system setting for dark mode" seem to only respect it when I set the **default** dark theme - that is, the "Yaru-dark" theme. How can I fix this? I suspect that there is some line that I have to change in theme files but I wondered if there is a more streamlined way.

For reference, here's my Tweaks appearance settings:
[image: Tweaks > Appearance: Materia-dark-compact is chosen]

Here's my system appearance settings (note that from the UI, it looks like "no style is chosen" - this makes me assume that Ubuntu doesn't recognize other themes as being in *either* light or dark mode?):
[image: System > Appearance: no theme chosen]

And here's Telegram, an app that has an enabled "Match the system settings" setting, clearly staying in light mode:
[image: Telegram chat appearance settings]

Also for reference: it's an almost clean and rather recent Ubuntu 22.04 installation with latest updates.